# How do I handle NAs when building a linear model?

Tags: r, nas

I am trying to build a multiplicative model in R, for which I created a formula within R. 
This seems to work fine, but when I am trying summarize this formula, I keep getting this error:

```
>summary(lm(MultiplicativeFormula, data = Sub_New_dfStorelevel))
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

I think that I know where it might go wrong, but I cannot find the solution yet.
This error might occur since I included some lagged variables and the first week of my observations is set to NA since I got no data for the first observation week -1. However, I also tried exclude those lagged variables in my model but the error still popped up.

I also checked my dataset on further NAs, but besides these lagged variables there were no NA's.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit easier to help if you try to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

That being said, the likely reason your model fails is indeed the NAs. I don't know what options you have tried, but the argument `na.action` can be used for this. Check out both `na.omit` and `na.exclude`. There's a pretty good discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11000/how-does-r-handle-missing-values-in-lm) that might be useful for you.